# Prevent default of dynamic tel link using jQuery (or JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm able to make it work this way:

```
$('a[href^="tel:"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('hello')
})
```

But this way it does not work for some reason, anybody knows why?

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href^="tel:"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('hello')
}
```

The weird part is that if I use regular links that are not , then it works perfectly. I can't seem to target dynamically created a:tel links this way. Anybody has a clue on how to achieve that?

Comment: I would assume it's because the latter relies on the event bubbling up the DOM before it's cancelled, by this time the OS integration has already been invoked and opened the program to handle the phone call. I don't see that there's much you can do about this. Perhaps in your CSS: `a[href^="tel:"] { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: The problem is I want to catch it, and then just change the number to add a prefix to tel depending on few conditions, so it needs to remain clicable... I proceeded to do a setInterval where I unbind and rebind that thing every second but ofc it cannot stay like this it's terrible...